# Scalability for intensive pdf generation tasks on a node.js app using puppeteer?

Tags: node.js, architecture, google-compute-engine, scalability, puppeteer

The goal of the app is to generate a pdf using puppeteer, we fetch the data, build the html template then using chrome headless generate the pdf, we then, return a link to the newly generated pdf.

The issue, is it takes about 7000 ms to generate a pdf, mainly because of the three puppeteer functions : launch (launch the headless broweser), goto (navigate to the html template) and pdf (generates the pdf).

So having around 7~8 seconds to answer one request, with more incoming requests or a sudden spike, it could easily takes about 40 to 50 seconds for 30 simultaneous requests, which I find unacceptable.

After many time spent on  research, I will implement the cluster module to take advantage of multiple processes.

But besides clustering, are there any other possible options to optimize the time on a single instance?

Comment: Do you need to execute the launch and goto steps for each pdf file? Can they be done once at the start? - just a thought

Comment: Yes they could, but I remember having some issues about a year ago, with a stress test, some of the pdf were blank.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are something to consider ...

1. Consider to call `puppeteer.launch` once per application start. Your conversion script will just check is browser instance already exists and use it by calling `newPage()`, which basically create new tab, instead of every time creating the browser.
2. You may consider to intercept `Request` as `page.on('request', this.onPageRequest);` when calling `goto()` and filter out certain types of the files which page is loading right now, but you don't need them for PDF rendering; you may filter out external resources as well if this is your case.
3. When use `pdf()` you may return back `Buffer` from your service, instead of using file system and return link to the location of PDF file created. this may or may not speed up things, depend on your service setup; anyway less IO should be better.

This is probably all you can do for single instance of your app; With the implementation above regular (couple of pages) PDF with a few images render for me in 1-2 sec.

To speed up things use clustering. Other than embed it inside your application you may consider to use [PM2](http://pm2.keymetrics.io/) manager to start and scale multiple instances of your service.

Comment: Thank you for the advises! I'm planning on having a similar implementation, my only worry is in regard to a stess test that I did a year ago when I was using a pool of browsers, some pdf were blank. Did you run into something similar recently?

Comment: @PCS-I The steps I described implemented in our service and we performed stress tests with about 40 threads against single instance of PDF converter. It doesn't scale much with this ratio, but never get blank PDFs. This is impossible with our implementation as we pass in HTML stream into node.js service and getting back binary of generated PDF. All external content blocked, inline images supplied with HTML as data URL; Blank PDFs may mean that your service overwhelmed and some requests timed out, but this would be improper error handling, other than issue with conversion.